# Enterprise Library 5.0 Configuration Console does not contain Autoscaling Settings

Tags: azure, enterprise-library, autoscaling, wasabi

I am using **Windows 7** and **Visual Studio 2012** together with the **Enterprise Library 5.0**. So far, everything works. I installed the enterprise library without NuGet because we made very bad experiences with NuGet and want to avoid using it.

I'm developing a Windows Azure application and want to use the Autoscale Block. Having downloaded the binaries of the Windows Azure integration for EnterpriseLibrary and unzipped them into the "*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Enterprise Library\bin*" folder, the configuration console does not show the Autoscale Settings block.

Does anyone know if there is another installation step I am missing here? I want to be able to configure the app.config file with the configuration tool instead of doing everything by hand.

Best wishes,
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to do:

1. Install the last version: [Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 Optional Update 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6836) (just to be sure)
2. Download the Windows Azure Integration Pack: [Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 Integration Pack for Windows Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28189)
3. When you "install" the Integration Pack it will ask you to extract it somewhere. Choose to extract it to the EL Bin folder: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0\Bin**
4. Right click your web/app.config and choose **Edit Enterprise Library V5 Configuration**. You should see "**Add Autoscaling Settings**" under blocks.

Comment: this is exactly what I did in the first place. I dont know why, but out of a sudden, the Configurator tool contains the new blocks... without me doing anything. This is really strange to me.

Comment: Yes, the Config tool was written to pick up the new blocks automatically based on the presence of their DLLs. This was part of the extensibility support we built in v5.